# How to determine if object in another AppDomain has gone

Tags: .net, remoting, appdomain

I instantiate an object of some class in other ApDomain using `CreateInstanceAndUnwrap()`. I can determine if this object resides in other domain by using `RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy()`. But can I determine if the real remote object has gone away (e.g. was garbage collected) without probing a call on proxy and catching `RemotingException`? Is it possible?